# How to find the probability of the largest $k$ values from $n$ sorted stacks being in the top $m$ items from each stack?

Tags: statistics

Let’s say I have a set $U$ containing some values. I randomly distribute these values into $n$ stacks and sort each stack from largest to smallest. Then I take the top $m$ items from each stack to form a set $S$.

What is the probability the largest $k$ values in $U$ are also in $S$? I can see trivially that the probability is $1$ if $m=k$ but that’s as far as I’ve got.

Comment: I suspect that in most cases simulation will be fastest. How is the random distribution done (with some methods there is a positive probability there could be some stacks with fewer than $m$ items)?